# How to extract basic descriptive stats on tables using schemacrawler

Tags: schemacrawler

Is there a way to extract stat information such as

Below based on type of data type like string int etc.
Count 
Mean
Min
distinct values
Max
Media
STD
null values
Avg
Top 10 values

Without using query on each table or something more efficient way without overloading the DB.

Also can we fetch few records for sample for each table when crawling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/) can show you the output of arbitrary database queries. Please download [the latest release](https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/releases/), and work through the example that shows you how to get output from a database query.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have tried the query execution. The general problem when executing queries on each table for collecting stats ex count of all rows in each column , avg, min, max of each column the database response severely impacts performance especially when there is large amounts of data.

Comment: Could you suggest.